# Importing data to Parse Users

Tags: parsing, parse-platform

I am trying to setup a Staging Environment by importing all classes from my production application. but when it comes to Users class , I face error which I have attached in screenshot
I cant use REST API to create all users as same Production users because their objectID will be different in that case. So I must need to import Users file but get this error. I have total 3.3k users in Projection app. I think this error comes after importing 882 users. As I can see there are now 882 users in Staging App

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm mistaken, all objects will be given new IDs, so you'll need to store the old IDs and re-link everything using a job.

Your old IDs can be put into a String column. Pointers will need to be re-done also, as the pointer will contain the IDs from the other environment.